# Router in Django to write only one model to datababse?

Tags: django, router

I have 4 models in my models.py. I am using multiple databases. I want to write only model into the another database I have added. I have default Router from Django documentation:

```
   def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write fileupload models go to galaxy.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'fileupload': #fileupload=app_name
            return 'galaxy' #database=galaxy
        return None
```

My model name is GalaxyUser. How can I modify this function so that when I do `./manage.py syncdb --database=galaxy` it only writes the model `GalaxyUser` to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to define the [`allow_syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_syncdb) method

```
class GalaxyRouter(object):
    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'galaxy':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'fileupload'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'fileupload':
            return db == 'galaxy'
        return None
```

Make sure the router is in a different file to the models (like `fileupload/routers.py`) and that it is installed in your `settings.py` file like so: `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['fileupload.routers.GalaxyRouter']`

Comment: Not working. It writes all the tables. I want to sync only GalaxyUser table.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I got the statements the wrong way around. I've edited  my answer - try that.

Comment: Nope. All tables are shown. I want to sync only GalaxyUser into galaxy database.

Comment: Alright, I just set up a test environment and tested this most recent edit. All works :)

Comment: It works but still there is one flaw. Django tables are not created in galaxy database but the other tables defined is created. I only want to create table called GalaxyUser. I don't want to create other tables defined in model.

Comment: That's what the first `if` prevents - if the target database is "galaxy", only allow if the app is "fileupload".